Streamlit session variable does not persist on chat
I am trying to implement a chat with Streamlit, where I need to keep a counter of words being exchanged, essentially starting from this.
So I initialize a session variable at the beginning of the main() function as follows:
st.session_state['words'] = 0

After the question has been asked and response has been provided, i.e. at the end of the st.chat_input block, after the spinner block, I calculate the count of words in the question and response (wd_cnt). I increment the count and write it:
st.session_state.words += wd_cnt
st.write(st.session_state.words)

The problem is: the counter is not incremented. The write statement above always outputs the value of wd_cnt, as if st.session_state.words was reset every time.
What am I missing?

Just to clarify; you do remember to have the initialisation inside a if statement so that it only runs on initialization? Streamlit re-runs your mainfile each time a change happens, and thus you would set word to zero if it is not inside an if statement.
Typical implementation is:
if "words" not in st.session_state.keys():
    st.session_state["words"] = 0

Here is a simple example of how a general counter looks.
import streamlit as st

if "words" not in st.session_state.keys():
    st.session_state["words"] = 0

def increase_count():
    st.session_state["words"] += 1

st.button("Increase count", on_click=increase_count)


st.write(st.session_state["words"])


Actually, I did not! I saw that in the documentation, but didn't think it was required, as I didn't realize that streamlit reruns the full main function every time! Now I get it, many thanks!
